# Would anybody want to go to an event in New York on October 26th, 2011?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There are rumours of a press launch by Canon on [October 26 in New York](http://www.canonrumors.com/2011/09/october-26-event/), which includes a shiny EOS logo.

If we could get the appropriate passes sorted, would anybody be in a position to go, represent the site, and write up an article for the [blog](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/)?

Comment: This is a great idea, and SE will do what we can to support anyone who is seriously committed to go. To see our general guidelines on events that a community member is attending: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/

Comment: I have a few contacts I can check, but I'm not sure we can be of much help getting you into this particular press event. I will inquire further, but more likely, perhaps a member of this community has some connections, if somebody in the NYC area would like to go and write about your experiences and the product.

Comment: Is there any more information on this event? Well we be able to send someone like Itai?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would go, I am not far away (Montreal) but someone would have to get me there. The Canadian press rarely do these things, so this would be a great opportunity for me.

Normally, I just get the press releases the day of. I would be able to write different summaries for the [blog here](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/) and [mine](http://blog.neocamera.com) which is also camera related.